# why am i not getting output - Data Structure , Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to get output after call insertNodeToEnd and displayNode. Bu I did not get any output. What is problem here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;

};

void displayNode(Node* head ){
    while(head!=NULL){//starting pointimiz NULL olana kadar döndür
        cout<<head->data<<endl; //NULL olana kadar her Node'un data'sını yazdı
        head = head->next;//ilerle
    }
}
void insertNodeToEnd(Node*curr , int data){
    while(curr->next !=NULL){
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr ->next ->data = data;
    curr ->next->next = NULL;

}

Node* head; //başlangıc node'unun adresini tuttuk
int main(){
    Node* Head = new Node; //bir node oluşturduk
    Head -> next = NULL;
    Head -> data = 500; //oluşan node'un datasını oluşturduk
    Node *iter = Head; //linked list içerisinde dolşacak iterator
                       //bu iterator'u head olarak tuttuk(artık döngüde iter'i başlangıç olarak kullanacağız)
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        insertNodeToEnd(iter,i*10);
    }   
    displayNode(Head);


}
```

I tried to get output after call insertNodeToEnd and displayNode. Bu I did not get any output. What is problem here?

Comment: *What is problem here?* - Not using a debugger?

Comment: Your `insertNodeToEnd()` causes undefined behavior here: `curr ->next ->data = data;` When this line is executed curr->next is a nullptr.

Comment: One other thing that should be suspicious to anyone reading the code is a function that adds nodes to a linked list that does not use smart pointers and there is not a `new` in the function or any way to allocate a new node.

Comment: I would prefer that linked lists tagged C++ actually made an attempt at C++ and not C.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `insertNodeToEnd()` is implemented all wrong.  It is not creating a new `Node`, it is accessing `curr->next` when it is not pointing at a valid node, and it is not taking into account the possibility of `head` being NULL when the list is empty.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void displayNodes(Node* head){
    while (head != NULL){
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void insertNodeToEnd(Node* &head, int data){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node *curr = head;
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = newNode;
    }
}

/* alternatively:

void insertNodeToEnd(Node* &head, int data) {
    Node **curr = &head;
    while (*curr != NULL) {
        curr = &((*curr)->next);
    }
    *curr = new Node;
    (*curr)->data = data;
    (*curr)->next = NULL;
}
*/

void freeNodes(Node* head){
    while (head != NULL){
        Node *next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
}

int main(){

    Node* head = NULL;
    insertNodeToEnd(head, 500);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        insertNodeToEnd(head, i*10);
    }   

    displayNodes(head);
    freeNodes(head);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/JBWAuJ)

That being said, consider using the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void displayNodes(const list<int> &lst){
    for (int elem : lst){
        cout << elem << endl;
    }
}

int main(){

    list<int> lst;
    lst.push_back(500);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        lst.push_back(i*10);
    }   

    displayNodes(lst);
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/BCyMVH)

Comment: thanks but I don't understand how the loop works in insertNodeToEnd. Can you explain please?